# How do I remove duplicated elements from a python array?

Tags: list, duplicates, element

###### What I just want to achieve is to be able to get a list with elemnts that aren't repeating

```
<current state>
results = ["Anna","Michael","Anna","Juliet","Juliet", "Anna"]

<expectation>
results=["Anna","Michael", "Juliet"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will remove duplicates.

```
results = ["Anna","Michael","Anna","Juliet","Juliet", "Anna"]
results = list(dict.fromkeys(results))
print(results)
```

Output:

```
['Anna', 'Michael', 'Juliet']
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_remove_duplicates.asp for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can conver the list to a set, which has no duplicates by definition.

```
results = set(["Anna","Michael","Anna","Juliet","Juliet", "Anna"])
```

If you need the type of the result to be a list, you can simply convert it back:

```
results = list(set(["Anna","Michael","Anna","Juliet","Juliet", "Anna"]))
```